# Why I can't select the Database for Typo3 during Installation?

Tags: installation, typo3, typo3-8.x

I run Docker on a Ubuntu. 
I took the [TYPO3-docker-boilerplate](https://github.com/webdevops/TYPO3-docker-boilerplate) as Basis 
Then I follow the  [instructions here](https://webdevops.io/projects/typo3-docker-boilerplate/)

During installation I came to part [image]
I cannot select the Typo3 Database.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The database is not empty. So you could either create a new one using the field below or, and I think that's what you want to do, you can use the existing, not empty one.

To use the existing Table, stop here in the Install Tool. Open the file

```
<yourWebroot>/typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php
```

There you will find a section where you can set your database credentials:

```
'DB' => [
    'Connections' => [
        'Default' => [
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'dbname' => 'typo3',
            'driver' => 'mysqli',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'password' => '<yourPassword>',
            'unix_socket' => '/tmp/mysql.sock',
            'user' => '<yourUsername>',
        ],
    ],
],
```

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InsideTypo3Reference/8.7/CoreArchitecture/Configuration/LocalConfiguration/Index.html

When you reload the Install Tool page it should not ask you anymore about database settings.

Answer (score 1):

The database needs to be empty and accessible for your user. Perhaps one of those two is the reason?

Comment: It says the typo3 database contains 54 tables, so it's not empty.