# (Solved) Cannot select database from dropdown menu during typo3 installation

Tags: database, installation, composer-php, typo3

Im trying to build a new website using typo3 v12 in composer mode. I`ve worked with typo3 before but I have never worked through the installation process to begin with.

Somehow I am stuck on installation step 3, which is to select a database that I had created previously. For some reason the database appears in the dropdown but I cannot select it.[image]

**My previous steps were:**

- did the whole composer setup, uploaded the files to my webserver and created the FIRST_INSTALL file to access the installer in my browser.
- passed installation step 1 (Environment scan)
- In step 2 I entered the name, host, password, port and user for my mysqli database

**Then what I tried to solve the problem:**

- Checked database credentials for typos
- as suggested here [Why I can't select the Database for Typo3 during Installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51771244/why-i-cant-select-the-database-for-typo3-during-installation) I opened up my settings.php and entered my credentials like this and then reloaded the installation process

  ```
  'DB' => [
      'Connections' => [
          'Default' => [
              'charset' => 'utf8',
              'dbname' => '<dbname>',
              'driver' => 'mysqli',
              'host' => '<host>',
              'password' => '<myPassword>',
              'unix_socket' => '/tmp/mysql.sock',
              'user' => '<myUsername>',
          ],
      ],
  ],
  ```
- I saw in other threads that people used username root and password root to connect to their database but I guess thats only possible when working locally?

  I expected to not be asked again about my database or at least be able to select the one in the screenshot above. Any suggestions what I'm missing??

Comment: You can't select the database because it is not empty: "Use an existing empty database" is the label. But the db has 39 tables.

Comment: This is so simple, I could punch myself...Thank you!!

Comment: @Loreen So could you please mark this question as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chris suggested above, the mistake was that the database was not empty. I don't know why it wasn't, but creating a new one solved the problem.